# Markup extension in XAML for binding to ISubject<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, system.reactive, markup-extensions

If I have the following view model

```
class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    ISubject<string> Name { ... }

}
```

and some imagined XAML code

```
<TextBox Text="{my:Subscribe Path=Name}/>
```

I wish the two way binding to behave that

- Subject.onNext is called when the text box is updated in the UI
- the text box is updated by subscribing to the Subject.Subscribe

As WPF only supports INPC directly my idea is to create a proxy INPC object
in via a markup extension

```
class WPFSubjectProxy : INotifyPropertyChanged{

    string Value { ... }

}
```

The proxy would be wired up to the subject as so

```
subject.Subscribe(v=>proxy.Value=v);

proxy
    .WhenAny(p=>p.Value, p.Value)
    .Subscribe(v=>subject.OnNext(v))
```

Note WhenAny is a `ReactiveUI` helper for subscribing to
INPC events.

But then I would need to generate a binding and return
that via the markup extension.

I know what I want to do but can't figure out the 
Markup extension magic to put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing specifically what you're struggling with, but perhaps [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2008/10/30/binding-to-a-markupextension-that-returns-a-binding.aspx) helps?

**EDIT**

The solution I (bradgonesurfing) came up with is below thanks to the pointer in the
assigned correct answer.

Nodes

and the implementing code. It has a dependency on ReactiveUI and a helper function in a private library for binding ISubject to a mutable property on an INPC supporting object

```
using ReactiveUI.Subjects;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ReactiveUI.Markup
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BindingExpression))]
    public class SubscriptionExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        [ConstructorArgument("path")]
        public PropertyPath Path { get; set; }

        public SubscriptionExtension() { }

        public SubscriptionExtension(PropertyPath path)
        {
            Path = path;
        }

        class Proxy : ReactiveObject
        {
            string _Value;
            public string Value
            {
                get { return _Value; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(value); }
            }
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var pvt = serviceProvider as IProvideValueTarget;
            if (pvt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var frameworkElement = pvt.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
            if (frameworkElement == null)
            {
                return this;
            }


            object propValue = GetProperty(frameworkElement.DataContext, Path.Path);

            var subject = propValue as ISubject<string>;

            var proxy = new Proxy();
            Binding binding = new Binding() 
            {
                Source = proxy,
                Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("Value")
            };

            // Bind the subject to the property via a helper ( in private library )
            var subscription = subject.ToMutableProperty(proxy, x => x.Value);

            // Make sure we don't leak subscriptions
            frameworkElement.Unloaded += (e,v) => subscription.Dispose(); 

            return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        private static object GetProperty(object context, string propPath)
        {
            object propValue = propPath
                .Split('.')
                .Aggregate(context, (value, name)
                    => value.GetType() 
                        .GetProperty(name)
                        .GetValue(value, null));
            return propValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I added a solution to show the answer I came up with. It works so far :)

Comment: Hi, I really like your solution but I have an issue: at runtime I always get a null DataContext, since using Caliburn.Micro's WindowManager first creates the View and then attaches the ViewModel, so the MarkupExt is parsed before the View gets its DataContext. Do you know any workaround to solve this? Thank you man!

Comment: Yeah I have a solution. I now use a varient of this that listens for datacontext changes. I'll look for it on monday. If I don't post it ping me again here.